# Any particular meaning to the expression 'stuck still'?

Tags: expressions, figures-of-speech

Stuck still, I would like to know what the exact meaning of this expression is. I think it's something like 'frozen in place' by a certain shocking or surprising occurrence or situation.

Comment: The expression is "stock still."

Comment: Not an expression - just the usual meanings of *stuck* and *still*. Stuck plus still. Stuck in one place so solidly that you are completely still (unmoving).

Answer (score 1):

The expression "stuck still" does mean "frozen in place."  It's even used in a couple of songs that I can think of.

*Florence and the Machine* croons in the opening lines of "[Dog Days Are Over](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/florencethemachine/dogdaysareover.html)":

> Happiness hit her like a train on a track,
>
> Coming towards her, ***stuck still***, no turning back.

"Stuck still" refers to being frozen in place on railroad tracks, albeit metaphorically.

Likewise, the *Arctic Monkeys* sing in "[Reckless Serenade](http://www.metrolyrics.com/reckless-serenade-lyrics-arctic-monkeys.html)":

> And now I'm ***stuck still*** wondering,
>
> how it's meant to be.

Again, this is referring to being frozen in place, unable to move forward or backward or in any direction, albeit metaphorically, again.

Just because these two examples use it metaphorically, it's just as often used non-metaphorically.  That is to say, it can be used either way.